# Limiting length of each "line" in Azure's Speech Translation

Tags: c#, azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am using this code example from Azure's speech translation (in C#) to build a multi-language subtitler for Zoom calls.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/quickstart/csharp/dotnet/translate-speech-to-text/helloworld/Program.cs

It's been ages since I've done any coding so I'm trying to get back into it, but what I can't work out is if there is a way to change the way to speech recognizer splits lines. At the moment, it waits until there is a couple of seconds of silence before finalising an answer. I would like it to do that, but also set a time where it will line break, say five seconds or so, if the person is speaking for longer.

Is that possible, does anyone know?

Very sorry if this is a stupid question, I promise I **have** looked for myself but can't find the right words.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this. This may not be the ultimate answer to everything you need, but hopefully it will help.

There is a service property you can set that will cause the intermediate results, delivered through the recognizing, event to be more "complete" and not get replaced as the recognition continues.

Here is a reference to the properties available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/queryparameternames?view=azure-node-latest

You set the property on the config object like so:

```
speechTranslationConfig.SetServiceProperty("stableIntermediateThreshold", "3", ServicePropertyChannel.UriQueryParameter);
```

There is also a property on the translation service that you can set to make it stable as well

```
speechTranslationConfig.SetServiceProperty("stableTranslation", "true", ServicePropertyChannel.UriQueryParameter);
```

You might have to play around with the values to determine the right threshold and some languages may have issues if the order of their sentences can change drastically before the end. Japanese is a good example of a language where you might only want to use the final recognition.

Comment: Ah, okay, so it's the finalisation that is taking the time, that makes sense. I will have a look at this later on, but this seems like what I need! Thanks!